# Como reverter a operação $unwind no MongoDB 3.4?

Tags: mongodb

Imagine uma coleção de produtos:

```
db.produtos.find()
[
  {
    _id: "produto01",
    cores: ["preto", "branco", "ouro"]
  },
  {
    _id: "produto02",
    cores: ["branco", "ouro"]
  }
]
```

Cada produto tem um campo chamado cores, que é uma lista de strings. Usando o `$unwind` no campo de cores resulta no seguinte:

```
db.produtos.aggregate([ { $unwind: "$cores" } ])
[
  {
    _id: "produto01",
    cores: "preto"
  },
  {
    _id: "produto01",
    cores: "branco"
  },
  {
    _id: "produto01",
    cores: "ouro"
  },
  {
    _id: "produto02",
    cores: "branco"
  },
  {
    _id: "produto02",
    cores: "ouro"
  }
]
```

Como se faz para reverter essa operação? Isto é, ir do resultado acima de volta para o original, depois de fazer `$unwind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) com [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) irá reagrupar o array ao objeto, dessa forma:

```
db.produtos.aggregate([{
        $unwind: "$cores"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "cores": {
                $push: "$cores"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Se cada produto tivesse mais campos, entao teriamos que indicar explicitamente cada um no valor de $group, senao nao iriam aparecer?

Comment: Sim @nbkhope, usando o operador `$first` nos demais campos (se não for array)